# VBA how to remove duplicate range in a bigger range

Tags: python, excel, vba, dataframe

I want to remove a duplicate range in a bigger range. Let's say I have data in column A1 and row 2-6 and Row 1 contains time (This is smaller range). Column A2 and end of column is bigger range.  so I have to delete duplicate data (Column A1 row 2-6) along with row1 timestamp and retain last time stamp in column.

I am inserting data from python into excel.

my python, vba knowledge is very limited.

How can I do this. remove duplicate is beyond my understanding.

I tried remove duplicate in many ways but no success. I don't want looping around as it will take more time but if it is only way I have to accept it.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: how to upload image

Comment: 14:50:33 14:51:19 14:51:55 14:52:29 14:53:04
48100CE 48100CE 48100CE 48100CE 48100CE
48300CE 48300CE 48300CE 48300CE 48300CE
48200CE 48200CE 48200CE 48200CE 48200CE
48400CE 48400CE 48400CE 48400CE 48400CE
48000CE 48500CE 48500CE 48500CE 48500CE